# Optimization problem on randomly selecting subintervals from a given interval with combinatorial constraints

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, stochastic-processes, combinatorial-optimization

We select uniformly at random $k$ pairwise disjoint intervals from a given interval $[0,s]$ with length respectively equal to $\ell_1, \ell_2, \ldots, \ell_k\ $, i.e., we select uniformly at random $k$ points $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_k$ from $[0,s]$ such that the intervals $[p_1-\ell_1/2,\ p_1+\ell_1/2],$ $[p_2-\ell_2/2,\ p_2+\ell_2/2],$ $\ldots,$ $[p_k-\ell_k/2,\ p_k+\ell_k/2]$ are pairwise disjoint and included in $[0,s]$ (this random process is equivalent to select the intervals in a sequential fashion, one by
one, such that the non-overlapping constraint is satisfied, i.e., the $t$-th point $p_t$ for $t\le k$ is selected from $[\ell_t/2,\ s-\ell_t/2]$ such that the corresponding interval $[p_t-\ell_t/2,\ p_t+\ell_t/2]$ does not overlap any of the $t-1$ previously selected intervals).

Let $P$ be a set of $n$ points belonging to $[0,s]$. We denote by $I_P$ the subset of all the randomly selected intervals that do not include any point of $P$. Finally, let $L$ be the expected sum of the length of all intervals in $I_P$, where the expectation is taken over the random selection of the $k$ intervals.

---

**Question:** What is  $\max_{\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_k} \min_{P} L$?

Comment: What prevents you from choosing $\sum_j\ell_j\approx s$ and then placing all points in $P$ very close to one of the endpoints to achieve $L\approx\sum_j \ell_j\approx s$?

Comment: Thank you @fedja for the question. I understand that I have to improve the text because it is not clear: The set $P$ is not chosen by you, because it is a set chosen "adversarially" and your maximization is over all possible $P$.

Comment: If so, then it should be *minimization* over $P$ and the question remains whether it is $\min_P\max_{\ell_j}$ or $\max_{\ell_j}\min_P$. In other words, I'm asking who makes the first move: you (choosing $\ell_j$) or the adversary (choosing $P$)?

Comment: Thank you @fedja . The adversary selects first set $P$, i.e., $n$ points on $[0,s]$, which remain hidden during the whole process of selecting the $k$ intervals. Then we have to select the $k$ interval lengths $\ell_1,\ldots,\ell_k$ to maximize the expected sum $L$ of all lengths of the selected intervals that do not include any point of $P$. I edited the question.

Comment: I presume you mean $\beta \frac sk$ for the conjectured interval width, but I'm not sure how to fix the conjectured $L$ so that it holds up in the case $k \gg n$. Note that in the extreme of large $k$, you can take $\ell_i = \frac sk$ to get $L = \frac{k-n}k s$.

Comment: Thank you @PeterTaylor .My conjecture is based on the following observations. Consider all intervals length equal to $\ell$ (to be determined later). Then we can partition $[0,s]$ in (about) $s/\ell$ equal pieces. The selection of the $k$ random intervals could be viewed as constraint to choose only $k$ pieces from the set of $s/\ell$ pieces. In the worst case the points of $P$ will be placed in $n$ different such pieces. The expected number of pieces of $I_P$ would be $k\frac{s/\ell-n}{s/\ell}$. Maximizing  $k\frac{s/\ell-n}{s/\ell}\cdot\ell$ w.r.t. $\ell$ we obtain $\ell=\beta\frac{s}{n}$.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, $k$ and $n$ are predetermined and so are effectively constants. Then $k\frac{s/\ell-n}{s/\ell}\cdot\ell = \frac ks (s\ell-n\ell^2)$ is indeed maximised over $\mathbb{R}$ when $\ell = \frac{s}{2n}$. But we need to have $k$ non-overlapping intervals, which is a constraint $k \ell \le s$, so you can only achieve that maximum when $k \le 2n$.

Comment: Thank you @PeterTaylor . Can we then state that $L$ is equal to $\mathbb{1}\{k\le 2n\}\frac{sk}{n}+\mathbb{1}\{k>2n\}\left(s-\frac{sn}{k}\right)$ up to a constant factor?

Comment: I wouldn't want to *claim* that, but I think it's a reasonable conjecture. I'd be tempted to go further and conjecture that the constant factors match the discrete problem where we divide $[0, s]$ into $m$ intervals of equal width and one player picks $k$ of them while the other picks $n$ of them; in this case we get $$\frac Ls = \begin{cases}\frac k{4n} & \textrm{if }\frac kn \le 2 \\
1 - \frac nk & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you @PeterTaylor . I agree with you (it's what I obtain with Mathematica).